# On hover background color covers image, z-index not having any effect

Tags: html, css

When you hover over the paragraph text in JS Fiddle the image gets covered with the background. Using z-index everywhere I could think of doesn't have any effect. (I left the useless z-index stuff in there so show you what I tried.) I also tried `pointer-events: none;` in various places.

I also tried this type of thing `elm1:hover elm2{}`, but that didn't help. I'm new to CSS and I'm applying what I have searched and found.

Edit: The problem: on hover background color covers image

Markup:

```
<div id="col2-middle" class="three-cols-middle three-cols"> 
    <a href="About.php#how-we-work- projects">
        <h1 class="h-big-font">Specific Projects</h1>
        <img class="col-img" src="3dplotCroppedWithFinancial.png" alt="3dplot">
            <p class="p-on-white"> 
                           XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX hover here to cover img XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                <br/>
                <br/>
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.three-cols {
    float: left;
    width: 29.33%;
    position: relative;
    left: 70.67%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
    min-width: 200px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.three-cols a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
.three-cols a p:hover {
    background-color: #ecebeb;
}
.col-img {
    float: left;
    padding: 4%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.three-cols h1 {
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
.three-cols p {
    padding: 0.5% 0 3% 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Here is my demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/pxD33/

PS - needs to be responsive and solution all in CSS and HTML.

Comment: So what is your problem exactly, and what is the desired behavior?

Comment: Its in the title "on hover background color covers image"  I'll add that in the text as well.

Comment: So you do not want the background to cover the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a>` is by default an inline-level element. Once you set `display: block` to it, it fixes the issue.

```
.three-cols a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/pxD33/2/

p/s: You don't need `z-index` for your case. You can safely remove all of them.

Comment: This does exactly what I want and it allows me to select the paragraph specifically. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you use a z-index with has to also have a position attribute.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the `z-index`es, and then change

```
.three-cols a p:hover {
    background-color: #ecebeb;
}
```

to

```
.three-cols:hover {
    background-color: #ecebeb;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pxD33/1/

Comment: That changes the behavior. I would like the over to be heading and paragraph specific as it is in my original post. I'll add that in the question for clarification. I thought that would be understood.

Answer (score 0):

updated fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxD33/3/)

just change anchor's display to block:

```
.three-cols a {
   display:block;
   position: relative;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000;
}
```

and give hover class to a not p:

```
.three-cols a:hover {
    background-color: #ecebeb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Terry said, setting `display: block` on your `three-cols a` element should do the trick.

If you want to have a "free hanging" picture on the left of your text, you could also use a media object.

Simply add the following rules

```
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
```

to `col-img` and `three-cols p`.

You can read more about the media object [here](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/).